# Firebase stores the Authentication JWT in Session Storage in my Angular App. Is that a vulnerability?

Tags: angular, firebase, security, owasp

We have created an Angular app that uses Firebase Authentication.  We have chosen to use Session Persistence to allow the user to refresh the page without having to log in every time.  We are aware that the auth JWT is stored in the browser session storage.

A recent pen scan identified the JWT as a medium level vulnerability.

Is this assessment justified?  If so, what are the alternatives for a Firebase/Angular app with these requirements?

Comment: The question is a bit vague and subject to opinion. Questions asking "[it is secure](https://overflow.tips/problematic-questions#is-it-safe-is-it-secure)" are problematic on Stack Overflow in that sense because we don't know your definition of "secure".  If you have specific security requirement and wish to know if a solution meets those requirements, that's something that can be discussed factually.

Comment: The bottom line is that a JWT gives its bearer authorization to do things in Firebase that the system has granted to that user, for one hour, especially as it relates to the security rules you've written to grant that access. You'll need to assess if that set of permissions is exactly what you want.

Comment: That second comment sounds like an answer Doug! 

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that a JWT gives its bearer authorization to do things in Firebase that the system has granted to that user, for one hour, especially as it relates to the security rules you've written to grant that access. You'll need to assess if that set of permissions is exactly what you want - we can't tell you if your configuration meets your security requirements or is at risk in a way that matches "medium level" (whatever that actually means).